# Changing input name using JQUERY

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm trying to change all the input name based on the list index of `<li>` but it seems like it's not changing at all.

```
$('.test').click(function() {
for(var i=0;i<$("li.songs").length;i++)
{
  var ob = $("li.songs").eq(i).clone();
  ob.find('input').each(function()
  {
    this.name = this.name+i;
    alert(this.name); //just checking if does it change
  });      
}
});
```

Now, the alert displays the right name I want, BUT no changes on the name when I inspect the element AND try to submit the form and display all the POST values.

Example expected output before changing:

```
<li class="songs"><input type="text" name="song" /></li>
<li class="songs"><input type="text" name="song" /></li>
<li class="songs"><input type="text" name="song" /></li>
```

After changing:

```
<li class="songs"><input type="text" name="song1" /></li>
<li class="songs"><input type="text" name="song2" /></li>
<li class="songs"><input type="text" name="song3" /></li>
```

NOTE: I DO NOT WANT the input named song to be an ARRAY.

Comment: actually that's a typical server-side task, you may generate correct name there. alternative - you can delete all this items and write back with JS (just I don't think that's a good practice)

Answer (score 39):

You are cloning the object, so the change is done to a copy rather than the original DOM node.

Don't use `clone()` and you'll be fine. Or do this:

```
$("li.songs input").each(function(i) {
  $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name') + i);
});
```

Answer (score 12):

```
$("li.songs").each(function(i) {
  $(this).find('input').attr('name', 'song' + i);
});
```