# How to empty the name attribute in form in jquery using source object on change

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I am trying to change the name to null/empty of all checkboxes which is unchecked on `onchange` event and on `ondocumentready` event using jquery.

this is my code

```
<div id="tab_4">
 <div class="col-xs-12">
  <input type="text" name="txtbox1" value="1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox1" value="1">
  <input checked type="checkbox" name="chkbox2" value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox3" value="3">
 </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#tab_4 input[type=checkbox]').each(function(i){
       if($(i).not(':checked'))
        {
         $(this).attr('name', '');
        }
       });
    });
    $('#tab_4 input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    $('#tab_4 input[type=checkbox]').each(function(i){
        if($(i).not(':checked'))
        {
         $(this).attr('name', '');
        }
       });
    });
</script>
```

But it makes all name attribute to null **even checked ones**.

I used this answer [Changing input name using JQUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118745/changing-input-name-using-jquery)

Comment: 1) Why exactly do you want this to happen?

Comment: to send only checked input values into database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to remove uncheckbox checkbox elements name to exclude it from form data. It is excluded by default. Check the following demonstration:

```js
const tell = () => console.log([... new FormData($('form').get(0)).entries()])

$(() => {
  tell()
  $('input').on('change', tell)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
<div id="tab_4">
 <div class="col-xs-12">
  <input type="text" name="txtbox1" value="1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox1" value="1">
  <input checked type="checkbox" name="chkbox2" value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox3" value="3">
 </div>
</div>
</form>
```